# Unable to get the value from jquery post in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have written this code in choose-item.php

```
function myFunction() {
    var values =[];
    $('#sortable2').each(function(){// id of ul
  var li = $(this).find('li')//get each li in ul
   var res = li.text().split("::");
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(res);
  $.post("choose-items.php", {"result": myJsonString});

console.log(myJsonString)//get text of each li*/
})

}
```

in the same page I have added this php script

```
if(!empty($_POST['result']))
 {
      $res = $_POST['result'];
 echo "alert('$res')";
 }
```

But I am not getting the result in my php variable.

any body can help? 
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: yes I have check post in console. I have value there

Comment: try to debug by adding print_r($_POST['result']);

Comment: you are not doing anything with the response you got. I mean you don't have success callback of `$.post(url, data, sucesscallback)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wrong variable names in $_POST to reference which actually do not exists then you will not be able to get the value of desired variable :

```
//$_POST['result[]'] do not exists but $_POST['result'] is what you passed in $.post
if(!empty($_POST['result[]']))
 {
      $res = $_POST['result'];
      echo "alert('$res')";
 }
```

You should correct the if condition to :

```
 if(!empty($_POST['result']))
 {
      $res = $_POST['result'];
      echo "alert('$res')";
 }
```

Also as you are using the same page to return your ajax response so 
 you should move your process logic for ajax at top of the page with a conditional check so that it only executes when ajax is fired and not on page load. Code should be like this

```
// Conditional statements to allow ease of HTML
if(!empty($_POST['result'])):
    $res = $_POST['result'];
    echo "alert('$res')";
    exit;
else:
    // your normal page content
endif;
```

You should do a print_r at top of you script to know what is actually getting posted, or you can inspect the console ajax request for same

```
echo "<pre>"
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>"
```

Comment: @Jai OP can use same page as long as he has relevant if(!empty($_POST) ) checks so that not all the content of page is returned by ajax but only the intended content

Comment: ha ha ha that is ridiculous.

Comment: @KyleE4K, any hints?

Comment: print_r is not giving me any output

Comment: OP hasn't wrapped a if statement around the page content, so the response would hold some of the page content as well as the response he only wanted.

Comment: @KyleE4K haha, thats what I pointed, OP can put a if(!empty($_POST['result']) ) { //process logic here and exit(); } at top of same page and return only intended response and not all page response

Comment: @Jai and Kyle so would that makes sense?

Comment: Your answer does not consolidate that, your answer clearly shows different context. If you update your answer to that, then its worth a vote up. @shivgre

Comment: @KyleE4K and Jai, thanks for hinting out, answer updated to include the conditional for ajax for same page

Comment: @KyleE4K thanks for pointing and hinting, I had that in my mind but didn't mention on my answer earlier :-)

Comment: i am getting blank array

Comment: @AzadChouhan what are the posted variables in your ajax request in console in firebug?

Comment: @AzadChouhan you must tell to jQuery the data are send in json format `$.post("choose-items.php", {"result": myJsonString}), function(result){alert(result);}, 'json');` <= just specify `json` at the end of the $.post method.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery could to be like this:

```
[...]
    $.post("choose-items.php", {"result": myJsonString})
        .done(function (data)
        { alert(data); }); // Your alert can be inside the function
[...]
```

PHP could to be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['result']) && !empty($_POST['result'])):
    $res = $_POST['result'];
    echo $res; // This is the data you're passing back
endif;
```

However, your response will not be accurate since you're not sending it to a generic handler page followed then by your response you wanted to send (`$res`).

The response the request will receive is **anything** that the handler puts out onto the screen, so in your case, your response will be your normal page.

> **TL;DR & IMO:** *You should create a new PHP file for handling this so your code is laid out and so your response doesn't get mixed up with page content.*

Comment: may be this too `echo "<script>alert('$res')</script>";`